# SwiftUI custom font loads slowly

Tags: swiftui, fonts, core-text, custom-font

When I used SwiftUI to build the app, I used a custom font in the project to display emojis (the font ttf file has 23.7M). When using custom fonts, the code is as follows:

ContentView will load slowly。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(verbatim: "\u{1fa84}")
                        .font(.custom("NotoColorEmoji", size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }                    }
            .frame(height: 400)
        }
    }
}
```

It takes about 3 seconds for the app to start and display the page.

If commented out `.font(.custom("NotoColorEmoji", size: 18))`， everything will be fine

So how to improve performance or preload the ttf font file?

I wrote a demo in [here](https://github.com/devyu/SwiftUICustomFontTest)，Is there any good way to solve this problem?